# Cross Validation with Panel Data of Variable Length

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, panel-data, prediction, cross-section

I have a problem of wanting to predict $y_t$ from $x_t$ and some lags given a series of $\{(y_t, x_t)\}_{t=1}^T$. To build my prediction algorithm I was hoping to use cross validation techniques such as the ones recommended by Rob J Hyndman is some of the other posts shared here on this stack exchange.

Unlike normal time series, however my data has another component to it: a basic unit of analysis.  In this case my data goes from what I mentioned before to $\{(y_{it}, x_{it})\}_{t=1}^{T_i} \quad \forall i\in \{1,...,N\}$.  Put into English, each time series is of an individual and each time series has a different length $T_i$.  Because of this, I worry that if I want to predict for any given interval at a specified time $t$, cross validation procedures that work like moving windows will have some leakage if they're done at the individual level.

I.e. my first thought was to use `TimeSeriesSplit` in the Scikit-learn package on each individual's series and then take the first partition of every individual as my training data.  But then I realized that some partitions will be at e.g. $t=5$ and others will be at $t=6$ and thus some of the covariates $x_{i,t=6}$ could provide leakage for $x_{j,t=5}$ even though you wouldn't be able to perfectly predict one from the other.

So basically my question is this: is this something I should be concerned about, and if so how should I handle it when I do cross validation?

Comment: Is the time index $t$ in absolute time (e.g. calendar months or so) or relative to each individual (e.g. months since the individual was first observed)? Is it plausible to assume that individuals are i.i.d.?

Comment: It's an absolute measure, so like 1 would refer to January 2000 for everyone. In the end because I needed a practical solution, I relied on Rob Hyndman's result that if the model errors are uncorrelated to a sufficient degree, then it shouldn't matter too much, but this wasn't the most satisfying approach